# ASP.NET 3-Tier / 3-Layer architecture - how to separate UI and BLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

I am currently studying towards my final year of a Computer Science degree, and working on my final project and dissertation. I will be using ASP.NET Web Forms and C# to create a 3-Layer project - I can't really call it 3-Tier as it will most likely never be hosted on anything other than my local PC for testing as it is for uni purposes only.

My main question is this:

From my understanding, the idea of 3-Layer is that the BLL references the DAL, and the UI references the BLL to create complete separation of concerns. However I have made a small mock up project following a few tutorials so get the hang of 3-Layer, and most basic tutorials still require a reference between the UI and BLL.

For example in the project I have created, which is a very basic Products and Categories type e-commerce system, I have created the Product and ProductDAL classes in the DAL, then the ProductBLL class in the BLL. With this setup, of only using one database table (forget categories for now), the BLL seems to only serve as a sort of interface between the UI and DAL, the methods are exactly the same as those in the DAL and only call the DAL version.

The problem is that to access the DAL via the BLL, I have to pass in a Product object to the BLL method arguments, which means creating a Product object in the UI first, which means referencing the DAL from the UI. Is this the correct way of doing things?

I can get around simple cases like this by creating a method in the BLL that takes the appropriate fields, e.g. strings and ints to create the Product Object and returns it to the AddProduct method. However when it comes to binding different product attributes to labels in the UI, I still need access to the Product object.

So essentially, do I need to make a load of methods in the BLL to access properties of the Product Object? If not, what kind of methods would actually go there, can you give me any examples of methods that may go in the BLL in this kind of Product scenario?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this has been asked before - I did read through a lot of posts about 3-Layer architecture but most are very basic and only access one table.

Answer (score 3):

> the BLL seems to only serve as a sort of interface between the UI and DAL

This is only because this application is very simple - just a CRUD interface at the moment. More complex applications have *business rules* that would be encapsulated in the BLL (and not be in the UI or DAL).

> I have to pass in a Product object to the BLL method arguments, which means creating a Product object in the UI first, which means referencing the DAL from the UI. Is this the correct way of doing things?

Well, there are several different options here:

- You can have a `Product` data access object (DAO) that is *shared* between the different layers. This object is not a DAL object, but the DAL uses it. It is called a **DTO** - Data Transfer Object.
- You can have several different `Product` object - one to be consumes by the UI, one by the BLL and one by the DAL and have mapping layers to translate between the different objects.
- Some combination of the above.

Comment: This answer has already addressed most of the important points I wanted to make but I will just add that your confusion in your question probably stems from the fact that you seem to be thinking that  `Data Access Layer` (eg: ProductDAL) and the `Data Model` (eg Product) are the same. They usually arent. The DAL is the code that is responsible for populating the model and  the model could very well be shared across layers as Oded explained above or even be different (think DTO's / ViewModel's etc)

Answer (score 0):

A common way of separating concerns is to start by having a project called YourProject.Entities or something of the like. This contains the main class definitions and you reference it when you need to get a large entity like a customer or a product or something of the like. Alongside, you have another project which acts as a repository. Depending on the technology that you are using this can either implement something like EF to get your objects from your DB or can contain methods which query your DB directly using straight SQL or stored procedures.

What you have to keep in mind is that these projects are primarily going to function based on user input. Your users will act and your program will respond. The idea though is that the actual business logic is separated from your UI and your data access. You can mix and match these ideas as you wish, but what I have tended to see in my professional experience is basic data constraint enforcement done on the DB access side of things, and data validation either done directly when creating your objects in the Entities project or in a separate EntitiesValidation project which takes entities as a parameter.

If you don't want to have a separate validation project, something to keep in mind is that you can implement business logic directly in objects using constructors and properties. Constructors can enforce logic on inputs before creating objects, and using full properties--that is to say this...

```
private string myProp    

public string MyProp
{
    get
    {
        // Some code
    }
    set
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

instead of this...

```
public string MyProp { get; set; }
```

Allows you to implement rules when accessing the data associated with those properties.

In the end, these questions can be answered many different ways and I am sure that every response to this question will give you different ideas and opinions on the best way to do things. For me, the two rules I always follow are DRY (do not repeat yourself) and code maintainability. By separating logic from data access from object design from UI, you will have a much easier time maintaining and updating your program when that time comes... even if it is just a school project ;).